# Troubleshooting timeouts with selenium for a specific site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

***Trying to fix a specific web-site timing out when it's tested with selenium***

Running tests on virtualbox and 90% of them return

```
"Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds "
```

What's strange is that web-site loads very quickly when I open it in Chrome on the same virtualbox... (just not through selenium)

**Troubleshooting:**

- Tried increasing the timeout limit in implicit wait
- Tried changing user agents (thinking may be the web-site itself is throttling down selenium tests)
- Tried increasing the ram on the virtualbox to maximum values

Not sure if anyone experienced this. Is there anything else I can try?

Appreciate any suggestions

Comment: 2 close suggestions with a note "unclear what is being asked". I provided the exact error message and explained that web-site is timing out. I'm asking how to avoid this and replied with a working solution. Can someone explain how this is not clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

Disabled image loading as per [Disable image loading with PHP Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56072260/disable-image-loading-with-php-selenium) and it seemed to have solved the problem. Web-site loading flies now

also more helpful info here: https://medium.com/dreamcatcher-its-blog/5-simple-tips-for-improving-automated-web-testing-or-efficient-web-crawling-using-selenium-python-43038d7b7916

There's a bunch of options which can be changed in ChromeOptions to speed things up like caching etc. Which I wasn't aware of. Hopefully it will help someone